# ¿Como se muestra una tabla en Android con Delphi 10.3?

Tags: android, delphi

Tengo Delphi 10.3 y quiero desarrollar para Android, el caso es que quiero llenar una grilla (como el DBGrid de las aplicaciones de escritorio).
¿Con que componente podria hacerlo? Probe un TGrid pero no tiene un Datasource ni nada.
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los Grids en **FMX** (multiplataforma) funcionan con `livebindings`, no con el sistema de `TDataset`/`TDatasource` al que estamos acostumbrados en VCL.
[Revisa este link de la docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/LiveBindings_in_RAD_Studio).

En el repositorio de Embarcadero, tienes también ejemplos de cómo se utilizan los LiveBindings.
[Ejemplo de LiveBindings con Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/LiveBindings.BindGridLinkFMX_Sample)

De todas formas, te recomiendo revisar el componente `TListView`, más apropiado para mostrar datos de este en móviles y pensado especialmente para ellos. Los `TDBGids/TGrids` de la VCL no se suelen utilizar en los dispositivos móviles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -2):

Puedes probar con el `TStringGrid`, es mucho mas avanzado que en el `VCL`, casi como el `DBGrid` y si lo manejas mediante condigo de forma personalizada haciendo tus propias `clases`, `metodos` y `helpers` sin usar `livebinding`, el rendimiento de la lista es 10 veces mas ligero, manejando miles de registros sin problemas.